# Как вырезать целый тег?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как вырезать например все теги  вместе с его содержимым ? и заменить на текст 'hoo'

Comment: а если один тэг внутри другого, на что заменять? пример бы текста и ограничения задачи привели бы

Comment: <div class="tagcloud"></div> все что внутри под 0 вырезать, как такое сделать?

Comment: Не используйте регулярки для парсинга HTML!

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('|<.*>(.*)</.*>|isU', "foo", $sContent);
```

Не учитывая вложенные теги

Answer (score 0):

> Вот решение, вам нужно только **[скачать](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery/archive/master.zip)** и подключить библиотеку **phpQuery** :

```
// Ищем тег div с классом tagcloud
// (другие теги с классом tagcloud удалены не будут)
$selector = 'div.tagcloud';

// Заменяем на строку "foo"
$replace = 'foo';

$str = '
    <p class="tagcloud">DELETE</p>
    <div class="tagcloud">DELETE</div>
    <div id="elem">Текст</div>
    <div class="tagcloud">DELETE</div>
    <div>Еще тег</div>
';

// Путь к библиотеке (ваша папка, куда вы скачали пакет)
require_once 'phpquery-master/phpQuery/phpQuery.php';

$pq = phpQuery::newDocument($str);
$pq->find($selector)->replaceWith($replace);
$text = $pq->html();

echo $text;
```

> **UPD:** Добавил замену найденных тегов на строку *foo*

Comment: @Andrii дописал замену найденных тегов.